# Is there a way to stop User Input in a JavaFX WebView?

Tags: java, javafx, video, webview

I was making a JavaFX WebView similar to this:

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
webEngine.loadContent("www.google.com");
```

I managed to use the `loadContent(String URL)` method to load an Embed Youtube video into a JavaFX WebView, allowing the user to watch the video. Additionally, I have added some parameters to the video URL to remove certain video aspects such as the video controls, full screen, etc. Because I can't disable user input from pausing or unpausing using these JQuery Parameters, I must find a way for a WebView to disable all user input, including keyboard, mouse, etc. Is there any possible method that would help me control this? Thanks.

Comment: Just `webView.setDisable(true)` seems to work for me.

Comment: @James_D Thank you sooo much! webView.setDisable(true) made it so the user can't interact with the node.

Answer (score 2):

As what James_D said, using the `WebView.setDisable(true)` will disable user interaction with the node. Problem solved